# iterating through two numpy arrays applying a function in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([np.nan,2,3])
b = np.array([1,np.nan,2])
```

I want to apply a function to the a,b, is there a fast way of doing this. (like in Pandas, where we can do apply)

Specifically I am interesting in averaging a and b, but take the average to be one of the numbers when the other number is missing.

i.e. I want to return

```
 np.array([1,2,2.5])
```

for the example above. However, I would like to know the answer to this in a more general setting (where I want to apply an operation element-wise to a number of numpy arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), which ignores `NaN`s:

```
np.nanmean([a, b], axis=0)
# array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])
```

Comment: nice. i used np.vectorize. Is that slow?

Comment: `np.vectorize` makes code shorter but it doesn't speed thing up. The doc notes for `np.vectorize` says *The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.*

Comment: @Lost1, I suspect that `np.vectorize` will have comparable speed to `pandas` `apply`.  I haven't used `apply`, but my impression from other questions is that is it iterative (at the Python) level.  Both will be slow compared to a compiled `numpy` function like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate some custom functions through NumPy arrays with the efficiency of NumPy's [universal functions (ufunc)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html),  the choices are

- [Write your own C code](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html)
- [Use the `ufuncify` method of SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html#ufuncify-method) to generate  code for you.

Here is an example of the latter, where the function is `exp(x) + log(y)` (since NumPy's ufuncs `exp` and `log` are already available, this is just for demonstration):

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify

x, y = sym.symbols('x y')
f = ufuncify([x, y], sym.exp(x) + sym.log(y))
```

Now applying `f(np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6]))` will return NumPy array `[4.10457619, 8.99849401, 21.87729639]` in a way that's not a Python loop but a call to (by default) compiled Fortran code.

(But in practice, you are likely to find that NumPy already has some ufuncs that do what you want, if combined in a right way.)